# What defines the max integer value for a URI port?

Tags: uri, port, standards

RFC 3986 [defines](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.3) the port of a URI as below -- zero or more digits. http/https URLs are defined to dereference over TCP, so ports would be limited to [1,65535], but in the general case of URIs of various schemes I'm having trouble finding a clear maximum.

For context, I'm writing a library that parses and handles URIs, and I want to make sure the library is sufficiently general.

> 3.2.3.  Port
>
> The port subcomponent of authority is designated by an optional
> port    number in decimal following the host and delimited from it by
> a    single colon (":") character.
>
> ```
>   port        = *DIGIT
> ```
>
> A scheme may define a default port.  For example, the "http" scheme
> defines a default port of "80", corresponding to its reserved TCP
> port number.  The type of port designated by the port number (e.g.,
> TCP, UDP, SCTP) is defined by the URI scheme.  URI producers and
> normalizers should omit the port component and its ":" delimiter if
> port is empty or if its value would be the same as that of the
> scheme's default.

Answer (score 0):

For TCP, UDP and SCTP port range is the same as your original message - [1, 65535]. That can be validated with appropriate RFCs ([TCP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.1), [UDP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768), [SCTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4960#page-16)).
If you want to support any other transport protocols you need to look into their specification to see the range. However quite likely it will be the same.

Comment: Right, but URIs are an open-ended spec. There could be another protocol that uses the port field for something other than ports as defined by those transport protocols, and therefore might not be limited to 65536 posts. What I'm asking is if there is anything that limits that number for _all possible_ URIs.